# Passing Params in a url using post method of httpClient

Tags: angular, http, post, parameters, angular7

I need to send an email in the url as a http parameter. I tried the same thing using postman and the code works fine but with the following code of angular it does not add the email param to the url. I am using angular 7 as the front end.

```
http://localhost:8090/api/auth/forgot?email=abcd@gmail.com
```

The email is sent to abcd@gmail.com when using postman and the above url.

Following is the frontend code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PasswordInfo } from './password-info';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResetPswdEmailService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  sendemail( emailinfo : String){//emailinfo is the email address
    let data = {email: emailinfo};
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8090/api/auth/forgot', {params:data});
  }


}
```

component part of the code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ResetPswdEmailService } from '../Service/reset-pswd-email.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forgotpassword',
  templateUrl: './forgotpassword.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forgotpassword.component.css']
})
export class ForgotpasswordComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private resetpswdemailservice : ResetPswdEmailService) { }

  mail : string;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.resetpswdemailservice.sendemail(this.mail)
    .subscribe(result =>{
    console.log(result);
    });
  }

}
```

Error in the console

```
http://localhost:8090/api/auth/forgot 400


HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8090/api/auth/forgot", ok: false, …}
error: {timestamp: "2019-05-07T10:53:58.230+0000", status: 400, error: "Bad Request", message: "Required String parameter 'email' is not present", path: "/api/auth/forgot"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8090/api/auth/forgot: 400 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8090/api/auth/forgot"
```

Seems that the params have not been added to the url.

I sent the email in the body of http and it works fine.The email gets delivered. So the problem here is with setting the parameteres.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try concatinating, like `return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8090/api/auth/forgot/?email=' + email);`

Comment: Trigger this api. Goto to browser inspect and select network and see how this link looks like after api hit

Comment: I have updated the question with the error. Seems to be the param is not added to the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to send the email as query param, not as request body, so you have to do this:

```
sendemail( emailinfo : String){//emailinfo is the email address
   let data = {email: emailinfo};
   return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8090/api/auth/forgot', null, {params:data});
}
```

Otherwise if it's this what you want, you need to know that it's not the correct way to use a POST method, because post data means use a body, so you're using as a GET method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead:

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = Params.append('email', emailInfo);

return this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:8090/api/auth/forgot`, { params: params });
```

Comment: You should mention that `HttpParams` does not encode characters like `: , " ...` for some reason. I stumbled upon this problem having to pass data in urlencoded format.

Comment: It doesn't work. I printed the params in console log and the values  that I enter are present. But the email has not been sent to my mail. There is nothing wrong in the backend cause the code works fine using postman

Answer (score 0):

If your request are post. Just change like this:

```
return this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:8090/api/auth/forgot`, {email: emailinfo});
```

Comment: Dont forget to call subscribe on your component code

Comment: I updated the component part of the code and error I get in the console in the question above